# Your fashion Christmas

Tags: meaning

I've seen this sentence [here](https://www.puntroma.com/ES/es).
Shouldn't it be "your Christmas fashion"? If it's right, what does it mean?

[image]

Comment: You can have a merry Christmas, a family Christmas, a down-home Christmas, a Star Wars Christmas, an over-commercialized Christmas, and many others.  There's no reason that you can't have a fashion Christmas.

Comment: Further, saying "Your Christmas Fashion" would imply that the fashion was only appropriate for Christmas -- think red felt coats with white fur collars and a stocking cap.

Answer (score 10):

For **anything** written or said, in any kind of advertising, including all TV, movies, and music,

> **There are no hard and fast grammar or pronunciation rules.**

This is because the point of entertainment is to draw your attention to the advertising, and a good way for advertisers 
to do this is to violate some kind of rule they think you expect them to follow.

Consequently, if you think you see a mistake on TV or in a movie, pay no attention to it.
It's being done on purpose, and your best strategy is to ignore it -- it's just more advertising.

Comment: Whoa! I've never thought about it this way... Man, did you just solve TV ads and the general mayhem it accompanies? o_O

Comment: There seems to be a contradiction between saying that 'there are no . . . rules' and that 'advertisers . . . violate some kind of rule'. If there really were no rules, there would be nothing for them to violate.

Comment: That's because there are two senses of _rules_ here. One is the kind of rules like pay your taxes that you have to obey, and the other is the kind of rules like wearing clothes that simply describe the way you behave.  The laws of grammar are self-enforcing; if you really break them, nobody can understand you.

Answer (score 3):

A "family Christmas" is a Christmas spent with ones family. (e.g. [How to survive family Christmas](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2011/dec/23/how-to-survive-family-christmas))

They are potentially trying to imply that shopping for fashion during Christmas is another strand of a well balanced Christmas.

Comment: I would agree with you, but given the fact that this is a Spanish brand I still think it's just a simple mistake. Nevetheless, they have given us food for thought, albeit unintentionally.

Answer (score 3):

It's a formula, used typically in advertising.  It means a Christmas in which fashion plays a prominent role.  A similar term: "an adventure holiday" is one that you have adventures on.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me to depend on which word you deem the noun (subject or object) and which you deem the adjective.

If one talks of *a family Christmas*, *a religious Christmas*, *an over-indulgent Christmas*, *sporting Christmas*, then *Christmas* is clearly the noun that the other words (adjectives) are describing, and *fashion Christmas* seems to fit with them.

However considering that one could talk of *Spring fashion*, *Easter fashion*, *Parisian fashion*, *Beach fashion* etc., then among them *Christmas fashion* would be in order, with fashion a noun qualified by the adjective *Christmas*.

Answer (score 2):

In English, one way to build a [nominal](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/glossaryoflinguisticterms/WhatIsANominal.htm) is to string a bunch of nouns together (see [Chapter 12](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi93pGF9dnJAhUDbSYKHazuC48QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.uccs.edu%2F~jkalita%2Fwork%2Fcs589%2F2010%2F12Grammars.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEWeA5jRKpq3r9MwWJ5Mg0wH3Y9qw&sig2=xDMMlN1aq0SQYFV_30yonA) of Jurafsky and Martin's *Speech and Language Processing*). Here are some examples of nominals built in this way.

> Mineta staggered to a stall and threw up, splurting the remains of a **hotel breakfast** into the **toilet bowl**. **Milk tea**, **orange juice**, and a **blueberry muffin**. Her briefcase had burst open, spilling **trial transcripts** and **evidence bags** across the **courthouse bathroom floor**. This was shaping up to be a hell of a **family Christmas**.

The **ad copy** you noticed is another example of this construction. As Martin Smith [points out](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/293673/71987), just as a "family Christmas" is a Christmas celebration centered around family, a "fashion Christmas" suggests a Christmas celebration centered around fashion.